# How can I count the number of seconds a window is open?

Tags: javascript, popup

I'm trying to write a script where I need a timer to count the number of seconds a popup is open. I'm new to programming but I assume you use javascript for it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Within the pop-up, you can use the `unload` event of the `window` object to detect the window closing or navigating to a new page, having previously recorded the time it opened at the the top of the document. For example:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var start = new Date();

      window.onunload = function() {
        var end = new Date();
        var secondsOpen = Math.floor((end - start) / 1000);
        alert("Pop-up was open for " + secondsOpen + " seconds");
      };
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
     ...
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

When it comes the calculating a certain time frame, I always use the date object, storing a new date in a variable once the popup is open and subtracting that value to the current date. Here's an example:

```
// Execute this when the popup opens
var popup_opened = (new Date()).getTime();

// And this way you can get the time (in seconds) that the popup has been opened
var current_time = (new Date()).getTime();
var time_spent_opened = (current_time - popup_opened)/100;
```

You can also retrieve the time the popup has been open multiple times using a function:

```
function getPopupTime() {
    var current_time = (new Date()).getTime();
    return (current_time - popup_opened)/100;
}
```

Comment: So shouldn't I check whether the popup has been closed? Or better, how do I do that?